# How do I create a set of a specific column in a csv dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, set, multiple-columns

In PANDAS, I'm trying to determine all the unique neighbourhoods in a csv file and am having difficulty in creating a set which is my proposed solution, could anyone help?

[image: 'neighborhood' column]

Comment: Rather than using images, please post example code or data in appropriate markups. This helps people replicate, debug and solve your problems easier.

Comment: Noted, I will do this in the future, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'unique' to get all the unique values, and if you want to create a set from the return value, just use set().

**Example:**

```
uniques = df['neighborhood'].unique()
set(uniques)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load your CSV into a Pandas DataFrame and then use [pandas.Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get all the unique values.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['neighborhood'].unique()
```

I hope that helps!